# Twilio with different alphanumeric sender id

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I'm currently testing programmable sms from its website with an upgraded account.

I've sent two SMS the alphanumeric sender id for the first one **INFO** and the other one is **MxSMS** using the same number.

The question is, why is twilio using two different sender ids for the same number? and how do I make it send only on one sender id?

I'm using a US phone number sending to a Philippine number

Comment: Which country are you sending the messages to and what is the code you are using?

Comment: Hi @philnash, I'm using a number from US, and sending SMS to Philippines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When sending SMS messages from a country to another with an alphanumeric sender ID, we can't always guarantee that what you use as the sender ID will be honoured by the carriers.

That is because our primary goal is quality and deliverability, so we will choose the best carriers at that time to deliver the message. I can see MxSMS is the default sender ID for Digitel, hence why it got changed to that.

Having said that, if you contact support we can pre-register your sender ID with the carriers, so it would always be honoured. Another option to ask support for one of our preview numbers in the Philipines. In that case, the alphanumeric sender ID would also always be honoured.

Hope this helps you

Comment: Glad that's useful to you. I don't think we currently have this in the docs, but I'll look into getting this added.

Comment: Are there any additional cost when pre-registering a Sender ID?

Comment: As long as you have an upgraded account you should be able to just use it. https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223181348-Getting-Started-with-Alphanumeric-Sender-ID-for-Twilio-Programmable-SMS